# Proving a set is path connected

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've been trying to prove that a set of points is path-connected
$$D=\{(x,y,z):0\le z-x^2-y^2\le1\}$$
I'm stuck at what approach to head, actually finding one or by some definition

First i defined $$F(x,y,z)=z-x^2-y^2$$ and showed that $$F^-1 (t\in [0,1])=D$$

I've tried to actually find the connected-path formula with no successes.
Is it possible to maybe try finding the invers of F and proof its  continues?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should try both and see what you can come up with. Then come back here if you still have not succeeded so that we can help you further

Comment: One of the best ways to prove path connectedness is to show that every point in your set is connected to some element $(x_0,y_0,z_0).$ I'd try $(0,0,0).$

Comment: @tav sheli No. You cannot say that. $F$ has the path connected image $[0,1]$ and its domain is $D$. Back to square one.

Answer (score 1):

Simply take assume $(x,y,z) \in D$.
Then let $F(t)= ((1-t)x,(1-t)y, (1-t)^2z)$ be your path. Clearly, path lives in $D$ and all maps are sent to $0$. Thus path connected.

Comment: And for any 2 random points in D, I can say the path is continues at (0,0,0) there for there's a path between every 2 points in D, but it must reach (0,0,0) somewhere in the middle?

Comment: Exactly! So basically, if you have a point that any path can reach. Then path connected! :)